# How can I select all keys in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

So I am trying to write an if statement that will check if the input given is not in dictionary[""];

However I haven't found a way to select all keys to do this to, otherwise I will have to rewrite the if statement for about 20 keys which would be inefficient

```
if input_a not in dictionary.values():
    print('hi')
if input_b not in dictionary.values():
    print('ho')
```

This will print ho and hi if i input a value which is in the dictionary or if i had a value that is not in the dictionary.

However if i do:

```
if input_a not in dictionary["key1"]:
    print('hi')
if input_b not in dictionary["key2"]:
    print('ho')
```

This will only print if input_a or input_b is in that specific key of values

Let me also say that each key has several word values

Comment: `if all(input_a not in val for val in dictionary.values()):`?

Comment: what's wrong with `if input_a not in dictionary:`

Comment: @jcfollower that will check *keys* not *values*.

Comment: are the values all lists?

Comment: Are there only certain dictionary keys you want to check? You said you want to check "about 20" keys; does the dictionary have more than that? Are there some keys that you *don't* want to check?

Comment: If you need to jump through hoops like this, maybe a Dictionary wasn't the right data structure to use in the first place.

Comment: Could you **provide an example**? What does `dictionary` look like? What could `input_a` and `input_b` be?

Comment: You are not being clear enough what it is that you want. You (currently) have two snippets of code; your description of what happens with the first snippet doesn't make any sense, and you don't say whether the second snippet does what you want. I also can't tell if you really have a separate input for each key (which is what your snippets *appear* to have), or just one input that you want to check against several keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are checking each keys value, simply check all values:

```
if input_a not in dictionary.values():
        print('Sorry, try again')
```

If you have iterables as values:

```
if not any(input_a in  ele for ele in dictionary.values()):
        print('Sorry, try again')
```

I used any as I presume if `input_a`  was equal to `2` and some keys value was equal to  `[1,2,3]` then it should return `True`.

Comment: This isn't *quite* equivalent.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes but using any will, I will edit

Comment: Yeah, when i do this, it just prints if the input is in the dictionary or not

Comment: @BlazBloz ...as opposed to what?! It might be helpful to provide a more meaningful example.

Comment: @BlazBloz, if you have iterables as values then you need the second example.

Comment: What do you mean by iterables?

Comment: @BlazBloz, a list, tuple etc..

Comment: Thanks, your second example worked, what are meant by 'in ele for ele in..'

Comment: @BlazBloz I think that by ele, he means element.

Comment: @BlazBloz, it just checks  if input_a is in any ele/sub element  in the whole list of dictionary values, it is the same as using a nested for loop but it evaluates lazily breaking if we find an ele that contains input_a

Answer (score 2):

the `all` solution is the best. I just want to add an answer that only adds a line to your code:

```
for key in dictionary.keys():
    if input_a not in dictionary[key]:
        print('Sorry, try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to get too specific with your code. All you need is `if input_a not in dictionary:` as so:

```
dict = {
'orange' : 'orange',
'apple' : 'red',
'tomato' : 'red',
}

dict2 = {
    'peach' : 'peach',
    'potato' : 'brown',
    'squash' : 'yellow',
    }

input_a = "apple"

if input_a not in dict:
    print "This isn't in dict!"
else:
    print "This is in dict!"

#Will print "This is in dict!"

if input_a not in dict2.values():
    print "This isn't in dict2 values!"
else:
    print "This is in dict2 values!"

#Will print "This isn't in dict2 values!"
```

Comment: My apologies, my first submission didn't include the proper answer. Answer now includes example for both values and keys.

Answer (score 0):

dictionary={'name' : 'Hari', 'age' : '24'}

value = 'address'

if value not in dictionary.keys():

```
    print ('Key not found')
```